# Is it possible to use jlink for cross compilation (bundling) application for different operating systems?

Tags: java-9, software-distribution, jlink

There is modularized application http://github.com/cuba-platform/cuba-cli that can be easily bundled with jlink using Gradle:

> ./gradlew bundle

At the moment it bundles application with Custom JRE image on Java 10 only with JAVA installed in operating system.

In bash it is:

```
jlink --module-path $JAVA_HOME/jmods:modules,
    --add-modules cli
    --output ./build/bundle
    --launcher launch=cli/Cli
```

How can I produce application bundles for Windows and Mac OS if I build my application on Linux? Can I just extract JDK for Windows / Mac OS somewhere and perform linking with those platform-specific JDKs?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You need to download the JDK for the target platform and then specify that JDK's `jmod` directory on the module path (that you specify to --add-modules).

Comment: @AlanBateman This, however, will not work vice versa (building Linux/MacOS images on Windows) because Windows is unable to set UNIX file permissions and executable flags for java launcher.

Comment: The issue of fixing up file permissions when you copy something (not just a run-time image) from one system to another can be an issue, yes.