# How to make a JRE for a 32 bits windows O/S with jlink?

Tags: java, windows, 32bit-64bit, jlink

I´m having troubles because I need to install a Java 16 app in a computer with 32-bit Windows. I don't have problems when I make a JRE with jlink for 64-bit Windows. Is there any argument that you can put in the jlink command to specify the architecture of the operating system?

Comment: Just use a 32-bit version of the JDK.

Answer (score 2):

It is true that *most* Java vendors (including Oracle) stopped supporting support Java on 32-bit platforms after Java 8.

However, at the time of writing this answer, Azul *does* support Java on 32 bit Windows and on 32 bit Linux.  All the way to Java 16 (the latest version).

So, switching to Azul Java 16 would be an option.  At least, it is worth a try.  (YMMV, etc.)

Reference:

- The Azul OpenJDK [downloads page](https://www.azul.com/downloads/?package=jdk#download-openjdk).

Another option would be [AdoptOpenJDK](https://adoptopenjdk.net/), though they don't have a 32 bit Linux offering.

---

> Is there any argument that you can put in the jlink command to specify the architecture of the operating system?

I don't think so.  According to the comments on [Is it possible to use jlink for cross compilation (bundling) application for different operating systems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50372512), you need to install a JDK for your target platform, and use the `jlink` from that JDK to generate your custom JRE.

My reading of the `jlink` manual page confirms this.

Answer (score -1):

well, now i have the answer, java doesn't support 32-bits Windows anymore since java 8. So if you need to do a java 9 o highter app to run on a 32-bits O/S you'll can't.

Comment: It's perfectly possible. You can use a 32-bit JDK provided by [AdoptOpenJDK](https://adoptopenjdk.net/).